# Error with Laravel file system after moving to new domain and hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

So i have just run php composer.phar remove and the php composer.phar install and then artisan migrate after moving my site from one domain to another and changing database. This all went ok and no error appeared that i wasnt able to quickly fix that why i ran the composer remove. However im getting a weird cant find file error which i havent had before. I am not sure how to fix this or where i am going wrong. This is the error I am getting:

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 109:
file_put_contents(/dfb46d0b690f78222831518b7c4c56c1dcef9f3b.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
in Filesystem.php line 109
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'file_put_contents(/dfb46d0b690f78222831518b7c4c56c1dcef9f3b.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied', '/home/danielma/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php', '109', array('path' => '/dfb46d0b690f78222831518b7c4c56c1dcef9f3b.php', 'contents' => '<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?> <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?> <?php echo $__env->make('templates.' . $config->currentTemplate . '.standardLayouts.main', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>', 'lock' => false))
at file_put_contents('/dfb46d0b690f78222831518b7c4c56c1dcef9f3b.php', '<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?> <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?> <?php echo $__env->make('templates.' . $config->currentTemplate . '.standardLayouts.main', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>', '0') in Filesystem.php line 109
at Filesystem->put('/dfb46d0b690f78222831518b7c4c56c1dcef9f3b.php', '<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?> <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?> <?php echo $__env->make('templates.' . $config->currentTemplate . '.standardLayouts.main', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>') in BladeCompiler.php line 116
at BladeCompiler->compile('/home/danielma/public_html/resources/views/welcome.blade.php') in CompilerEngine.php line 51
at CompilerEngine->get('/home/danielma/public_html/resources/views/welcome.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'config' => object(stdClass))) in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 53
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 201
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1085
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(MainController), object(Route), object(Request), 'homePage') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\MainController', 'homePage') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/home/danielma/public_html/public/index.php') in index.php line 21
```

I am not sure where i have gone wrong so help would be greatly appreciated.
These are my current php setting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pN9b.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the *storage* and *bootstrap/cache* folders have write permissions.
If you still get the error afterwards run `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`.

Comment: Ive changed the file permissions to 777 through filezilla and run those to artisan commads and nothing has changed. The .env file is correct.

Comment: Did you gave recursive 777 permission on storage and cache folders ?

Comment: @DanMarks yes, please make sure the inside folders have also the write permission.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs under [Installation > Configuration > Directory Permissions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation):

> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache` directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run.

Also check to make sure your `.env` file is correct.